# onChange set value of objects inside of object to state with form input in React

Tags: reactjs

Hi I'm new to react and I'm trying to add value from my input to my state but instead of updating it created a new value in the parent object.
(I'm new to stack overflow btw so please don't be to hard on me for not wording my question correctly)

Here is my state

```
const [ patientUpdate,setPatientUpdate ] = React.useState([
    {
        id: ,
        userID: " ",
        patientID: " ",
        patientInfo: {
            id: 1,
            email: "email@gmail.com",
            name: "David",
            age: 25,
            phone: "0123455",
            gender: false
        },
        delete: false
  }
  ])
```

here is my on change

```
function handleChangeEvent(event) {
    const { name, value, type, checked } = event.target;
    setPatientUpdate((prevPatientUpdate) => {
      return {
        ...prevPatientUpdate,
        [name]: type === "checkbox" ? checked : value,
      };
    });
  }
```

in stead of updating patient info name it instead created a new field in patient update.

Is there anyways to make it so that it update directly inside of patient info ?

Answer (score 0):

You are updating the patient details directly instead of patientInfo. Check the below one

```
setPatientUpdate((prevPatientUpdate) => {
  return {
    ...prevPatientUpdate,
    patientInfo: {...prevPatientUpdate.patientInfo, [name]: type === "checkbox" ? checked : value}
  };
});
```